# R-Studio setup with offline CRAN repository in Windows

Tags: r, cran

I would like to know what is the mchanism, if there is one, for setting up local CRAN repository in an environment that has no internet access. I have a windows environment but I would love to know if it can also be done in linux environment.

I have heard that I'll need to have a web browser to allow R-studio to find local repository. Not sure if it's true but I would like to find out all  the steps to set this R-studio with local repository environemnt.

The idea is to have a fully fuunctional R-studio with full CRAN respository available in an offline environment where any package can be installed easily. I couldn't find any source/link available online that details how this can be achieved.
I know R-Studio is setting a package management tool that allows this functionality but I would like to get this done without spending any money.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [miniCRAN package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=miniCRAN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by creating a local webserver using Apache and then downloading full CRAN repository (win binaries only). I also had to edit my Rprofile.site file by providing the link to my local webserver.